# Why not get the desired output from stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, linq-to-sql, stored-procedures

To fulfill one of my requirements I need to pass a SQL query as a parameter to a stored procedure.

My stored procedure syntax is:

```
create PROCEDURE spSelect 
    @Query VARCHAR(500)
AS 
    EXEC( @Query)  
    return
```

To execute that stored procedure, I use this C# code:

```
DataContex db=new DataContex();
    String sSQL = " SELECT OrderID,ShipName FROM dbo.Orders";
    var result = db.spSelect(sSQL);
```

After execution, the `result` is `0`.

Need help to understand what happen, why not I get desired output

If have any query please ask, thanks in advance

Comment: You need to use something like the `SqlDataReader` in order to actually **read** the result set that you get back. You're not getting back all the `OrderID, ShipName` into a single variable `result` .....

Comment: marc_s,thanks for reply ,in linq how to use SqlDataReader

Comment: Does this actually compile?  What type of object is `db`?  I've not seen the syntax of `Object.<StoredProcedureName>` before...  There are possibly hundreds of ways to call stored procedures using .NET and I don't think what you have is one of them.  I recommend using a search engine first.  An article to get you started http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d7125bke.aspx.  I recommend further research and reading beyond that article.

Comment: "I need to pass a SQL query" is not a requirement. It's "I can't think of a better way to do this". Or it's "The DBAs won't let me execute SQL directly, I have to go through stored procedures - here's hoping they don't audit this one"

Comment: Damien_The_Unbeliever,yah! you are right.need to execute sql query dynamically,sql query =parameter of a sp

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the [sp_executesql (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx) to execute it:

```
create PROCEDURE spSelect 
@Query VARCHAR(500)
AS 
    EXECUTE sp_executesql @Query
 return
```

Comment: Jeremy Thompson,thanks for reply try your syntax ,but failed to get result

Comment: What Jeremy has identified is a problem you will face later once you deal with your C# challenges.  The SP you wrote assumes you are passing in dynamic sql.  `EXEC` will not execute dynamic sql. You must use `EXECUTE sp_executesql` in order to use dynamic sql.  Please read up on this http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20815/Building-Dynamic-SQL-In-a-Stored-Procedure.